# SVG clipPath issue

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I have a svg tag with two circle elements inside that which are the same as each other. with same X and Y and R. but when I put one of them inside a clipPath and link it to an image or div, the position of the clipped circle will change. what is the problem about it?
It would be appreciated if anyone can help.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="clip-background"></div>
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <clipPath id="clipping-area">
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100">
  </clipPath>
    <circle class="circle-border" cx="200" cy="200" r="100">
</svg>
```

And here is the css code:

```
.clip-background{
  position:absolute;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background-color:pink;
  clip-path: url(#clipping-area);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipping-area);
}
.circle-border{
  fill:none;
  stroke:#666;
  stroke-width:2;
}
```

[codepen here.](http://codepen.io/NavidNazarian/pen/beeJmW)

Comment: You can't edit a question such that the answer no longer makes sense. If you have additional questions ask them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because in your clipPath, the coordinates of the circle are being treated as being relative to the top left of the page.  Whereas the circle coordinates in the SVG are relative to the top left of the `<svg>`.  But the SVG is affected by the default margins/paddings on the HTML `<body>`.  And so is not positioned in the same place.

If you get rid of the body margins in the standard way:

```
BODY {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

you will see they both line up.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjjOzm

Comment: That's right but in my main project I still have the same problem and even the size of the clipped circle is smaller than the other. I've set the height of the svg to 100% and the width to auto, but even in fixed size in pixel, I have the same problem!

Comment: when I inspect clipped circle element in chrome dev tools, it highlights the element in the right place as same as the other circle, but the masked image part is in other position and in top of the page and with smaller size! do you have any idea about it? I wish I could show you a screen shot... @Paul LeBeau